# SQL Server permission to use the bulk load statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I have the below query which works fine in the SSMS. But when I include the same script as a job step, it fails with SQL permission to use the bulk load statement

```
DECLARE @FileContents  VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @filepath VARCHAR(1000)
SET @FileContents = NULL

SET @filepath ='C:\XXXX\6.0_Script_to a.sql'
SET @FileContents = (SELECT BulkColumn 
                     FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\XXXX\6.0_Script_to a.sql', SINGLE_BLOB) a)   
SET @FileContents = REPLACE(@FileContents, '[SQLSTATE 01000]', '') 
SET @FileContents = REPLACE(@FileContents, 'Job ', '--Job ')
SET @FileContents = REPLACE(@FileContents, ' GO ', CHAR(10) + ' GO ' + CHAR(10)) 
SET @FileContents = REPLACE(@FileContents, 'Script ', '--Script ')

PRINT @FileContents
```

But I have checked my credentials have bulkadmin permission and also executed the below query in server

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'xxxxxx', @rolename = N'bulkadmin'
```

Let us know what I need to include the script to be part of sqljob step

Comment: What service account is set to SQL Server Agent servce?

Comment: SQL server agent service running with Network Service

Comment: So probably is that Network Service have no permission. Try to change account to your account to check it. With your account job should execute normally. Or you can create new login "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" and grant permissions to this login

Comment: Please post exact error message

Comment: Executed as user: <DOMAIN\USERNAME>.
 You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 4834).  The step failed.

Comment: Found the solution, I had to remove the entry in the 'Run as User' 'Advanced' tab on job step.

It started working.

Thanks